# Floating Point Number issue JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

*I'm struggling to resolve a Floating Point Number issue where var change returns as 0.0999 recurring, and i need to return 0.01 (one penny). The code works fine, except the very last penny, because of this issue.
This is my first post here so please excuse formatting...*

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
    var change = cash - price;     
    var totalCid =0;

    for(var i = 0; i < cid.length; i++) totalCid += cid[i][1];      

    var returnArr = [["PENNY",0], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0],["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]];

    function hasValue (value) {return value[1] > 0;}

    if(change>totalCid) {
        return "Insufficient Funds";
    }
    else if(change==totalCid) {
        return "Closed";
    }

    else {
        while(change >= 0.01) {

            if (change >=100 && cid[8][1] >= 100){
                change -= 100;
                cid[8][1] -= 100;
                returnArr[8][1] += 100;
            }
            else if (change >= 20 && cid[7][1] >= 20){
                change -= 20;
                cid[7][1] -= 20;
                returnArr[7][1] += 20;
            }
            else if (change >= 10 && cid[6][1] >= 10){
                change -= 10;
                cid[6][1] -= 10;
                returnArr[6][1] += 10;
            }
            else if (change >= 5 && cid[5][1] >= 5){
                change -= 5;
                cid[5][1] -= 5;
                returnArr[5][1] += 5;
            }
            else if (change >= 1 && cid[4][1] >= 1){
                change -= 1;
                cid[4][1] -= 1;
                returnArr[4][1] += 1;
            }
            else if (change >= 0.25 && cid[3][1] >= 0.25) {   
                change -= 0.25;
                cid[3][1] -= 0.25;
                returnArr[3][1] += 0.25;
            }
            else if (change >= 0.10 && cid[2][1] >= 0.10){
                change -= 0.10;
                cid[2][1] -= 0.10;
                returnArr[2][1] += 0.10;
            }
            else if (change >= 0.05 && cid[1][1] >= 0.05){
                change -= 0.05;
                cid[1][1] -= 0.05;
                returnArr[1][1] += 0.05;
            }
            else if (change >= 0.01 && cid[0][1] >= 0.01){
                change -= 0.01;
                cid[0][1] -= 0.01;
                returnArr[0][1] += 0.01;
            }  
            else return "Insufficient Funds";

        }
        return returnArr.filter(hasValue).reverse();
    } 
}
```

Calling

```
checkCashRegister(3.26, 100.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]);
```

should return

[["TWENTY", 60.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["FIVE", 15.00], ["ONE", 1.00], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.20], ["PENNY", 0.0**4**]]

but it returns

[["TWENTY", 60.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["FIVE", 15.00], ["ONE", 1.00], ["QUARTER", 0.50], ["DIME", 0.20], ["PENNY", 0.0**3**]]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your actual question?  If you're wondering _why_ it does this, then your answer is here: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)  If you're wondering how to fix it, then the very short answer is that it's rarely a good idea to mix floating point with monetary values.

Comment: Yeah. I would multiply the incoming values by 100 and convert them to ints. You could also improve the performance of your algo there by using division and modulo I think... But that is a different question...

Comment: resolved using this method, thanks! @karina

Answer (score 0):

You could get the expected answer ["PENNY", 0.04] by making the following modification for 'change' in the 'else if' condition which deals with PENNY

change = change.toFixed(2) - 0.01;